# find and replace string from multiple files in a folder using python

Tags: python, string, directory, find-replace

I want to find string e.g. "Version1" from my files of a folder which contains multiple ".c" and ".h" files in it and replace it with "Version2.2.1" using  python file.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using os, glob and ntpath. The results are saved in a directory called "output". You need to put this in the directory where you have the .c and .h files and run it.

Create a **separate directory** called output and put the edited files there:

```
import glob
import ntpath
import os

output_dir = "output"

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

for f in glob.glob("*.[ch]"):
    with open(f, 'r') as inputfile:
        with open('%s/%s' % (output_dir, ntpath.basename(f)), 'w') as outputfile:
            for line in inputfile:
                outputfile.write(line.replace('Version1', 'Version2.2.1'))
```

Replace strings **in place**:

**IMPORTANT**! Please make sure to back up your files before running this:

```
import glob

for f in glob.glob("*.[ch]"):
    with open(f, "r") as inputfile:
        newText = inputfile.read().replace('Version1', 'Version2.2.1')

    with open(f, "w") as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(newText)
```

Comment: I tried your code. I put my directory path instead of "output" and placed python file with the same folder where my all files are. But when i run your code all the contents of files erased. I don't know why?

Comment: You don't need to put your directory path instead of output. Please put this script in the folder with your .c and .h files and run it.

Comment: Thanks Ashish it works. But there is another directory created called "output". But I want my changes in that same directory files. Don't want to create another directory

Comment: It would be ok if we create a temporary file named with "output" , copy the data of all the files in that directory and paste it in our original directory in which 'Version1' string was there. Then delete this temporary file "output"

Comment: @Meera, added code for in place replacement, as requested.

Comment: What if I don't want to remember my previous string for e.g. "Version1", I only know that I need to update my version for e.g "Version2" after the string "@VERSION  Version2". Can I do that?Simply I don't know the previous version.

Comment: i suggest you look into some regex based solution